# Is "very ampleness" etale/fpqc local on the base (under reasonable conditions?)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $f : X\rightarrow S$ be a quasicompact morphism of schemes, and $\mathcal{L}$ a line bundle on $X$.

Let $g : S'\rightarrow S$ be a surjective map, and $f' : X_{S'}\rightarrow S'$ the base change.

Under what conditions on $f,g$ does $\mathcal{L}|_{X_{S'}}$ being very ample imply that $\mathcal{L}$ is very ample?

Certainly this holds if $g$ is a Zariski covering. Does it hold if $g$ is an etale covering? fpqc covering? (possibly with some conditions on $f$?)

Part of the problem is that I'm having difficulty finding cohomological characterizations of very ampleness.

Comment: If $g$ is a quasi-affine morphism, its base change i.e. the map from $X_{S'}$ to $X_S$ would also be quasi-affine. Note that pullback of ample line bundles under quasi-affine morphisms is ample. This is true for etale morphisms since they quasi-finite and subsequently quasi-affine. (If everything is separated.) (This is for ampleness though not sure about very ampleness.)

Comment: I do not know about etale but there is a finite map between smooth curves (so fpqc) for which it does not work https://ayoucis.wordpress.com/2014/11/11/weird-example-pullback-of-very-ample-by-finite-is-not-very-ample/

Comment: @virkkunen that post shows it's not fppf-local on the source; this question is about local on the target.

Comment: I think property (4) of Tag [01VR](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01VR) looks promising. Formation of $f_* \mathscr L$ commutes with flat base change; see Tag [02KH](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02KH). Thus the first condition is fpqc-local on the target by Tag [02KR](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02KR); the second by the definition of faithful flatness, and the third by Tag [02L8](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02L8).

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn Fantastic! If you would like to write that as an answer I would happily accept!

Answer (score 4):

A good cohomological characterisation of very ampleness is criterion (4) of [Tag [01VR](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01VR)]: $f$ is quasi-separated, the counit $\psi \colon f^*f_* \mathscr L \to \mathscr L$ is surjective, and the induced map $r_{\mathscr L, \psi} \colon X \to \mathbf P(f_*\mathscr L)$ is an immersion.

Firstly, note that formation of $f_* \mathscr L$ (and therefore of $\mathbf P(f_*\mathscr L)$) commutes with flat base change [Tag [02KH](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02KH)]. Also note that $r_{\mathscr L,\psi}$ is automatically quasi-compact, since $f$ is quasi-compact and $\mathbf P(f_*\mathscr L) \to S$ is quasi-separated [Tag [03GI](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/03GI)].

This allows us to check that all three criteria are fpqc-local on the target:

- $f$ is quasi-separated: this is fpqc-local by [Tag [02KR](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02KR)].
- the counit $\psi \colon f^*f_*\mathscr L \to \mathscr L$ is surjective: this is fpqc-local since formation of $f_* \mathscr L$ commutes with flat base change and since surjectivity of a morphism of quasi-coherent sheaves is fpqc-local (this follows from faithful flatness).
- the induced map $r_{\mathscr L,\psi} \colon X \to \mathbf P(f_*\mathscr L)$ is a (quasi-compact) immersion: this is fpqc-local by [Tag [02L8](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02L8)].